# Limitation on number of retrievable people in user's circle

Tags: android, google-plus

I am using gplus API for my Android project. I can reach user's circle with this code

```
public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult peopleData) {
  if (peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
    PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
    try {
      int count = personBuffer.getCount();
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Display name: " + personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
      }
    } finally {
      personBuffer.release();
    }
  } else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error requesting people data: " + peopleData.getStatus());
  }
}
```

But there is a limitation: I can retrieve only 100 people in my account. How can I exceed this limit?

Comment: The example on this page https://developers.google.com/+/domains/circles/people shows `listPeople.setMaxResults(100L);` have you tried setting that attribute to something higher than 100?

Comment: i am using android api, I think it is little different. Because PlusDomains cannot be resolved to a type in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution. We should use "getNextPageToken()" and with this we can get large result. 
These following links will help you,

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People.LoadPeopleResult

https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE/blob/master/googleplus%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgithub%2Fgorbin%2Fasne%2Fgoogleplus%2FGooglePlusSocialNetwork.java#L473